# Is "transient detection" exclusive to Freescale?

Tags: sensor, accelerometer, motion, freescale

I'd like to detect the dynamic component of acceleration, i.e. the change in acceleration, and generate an interrupt when such change is detected. I see that [MMA8451/2/3](http://cache.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN4071.pdf) calls this "Transient Detection".

However, I can't seem to find any other manufacturer supporting "transient detection". I've tried Analog, Kionix, STM, etc. Is it something exclusive to Freescale accelerometers or is it coined up by their marketing department?

I'm not certain of the mechanics, but "Transient Detection" seems to involve a HPF. Does that mean any accelerometer that has a HPF onboard will likely be equivalent to "Transient Detection"?

**UPDATE**

I believe the MMA8451 is a digital device since it supports I2C.

Comment: so the sensor gives you acceleration and you want the derivative of acceleration?  derivative is just y[n] = x[n] - x[n-1] for sample n

Comment: Yes. I've only played with MMA8452, but 'motion detection' doesn't respond to gentle nudges. Transient detection can pick up even very slow acceleration because it takes out the dynamic acceleration component. I'm not sure if that's what HPF is supposed to do though.

Comment: HPF and differentiation are the same thing at low frequencies, but HPF flattens out at high frequencies.  diff goes to infinite gain at infinite frequency.  is this an analog or digital signal from the accelerometer?

Comment: ok in that case an analog differentiator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiator#Active_differentiator

Comment: I see. How come HPF is differentiation for analogue MEMS?

Comment: both have 6 dB/octave roll off at low frequencies: http://www.electronicshub.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Frequency-Response-of-Practical-Differentiator.jpg http://www.electronicshub.org/operational-amplifier-as-differentiator/

Comment: Sorry, actually it's digital and not analogue. Just found it.

Comment: So then differentiation is just reading the value and subtracting the previous sample from the current sample (assuming they are equally spaced in time)

Comment: @endolith Both MMA8452 or MPU-6050 are digital though (I2C support). ADXL345 doesn't mention "transient detection" at all, but it's supposed to be a superior accelerometer. The MPU6050 claims that "Accelerometer measurements are passed through a configurable digital high pass filter (DHPF) in order to eliminate bias due to gravity." So it seems that's what the HPF is supposed to do - even if it's a digital device?